# The real orthonormal matrix with the most uniformly distributed absolute valued entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

What is the solution to the following expression? Denote the set of real valued $n\times n$ orthonormal matrices as $M_n$
$$\min_{Q\in M_n}\max_{i,j}|Q_{i,j}|$$

The first thing coming to mind is to make all entries of equal absolute value but taking on different signs. That fails to work, though.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to state his reason for the downvote?

Comment: This feels a bit like a packing problem! We're looking for $n$ vectors of length 1 that are all perpendicular, fitting in the smallest axis-aligned cube centered at the origin. Have you tried working this out computationally for small $n$?

Comment: @TomKern: That is correct. It is a quadratic programming problem. I have not tried it  numerically for small $n$'s yet as I do not currently have a quadratic programming package at hand.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest avoiding the nondifferentiability of both max and absolute value by reformulating as follows.  Introduce decision variable $z$ to represent $\max_{i,j} Q_{i,j}^2$, which will be minimized for the same $Q$ as your original problem.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
z &\ge Q_{i,j}^2 &&\text{for all $i,j$} \\
\sum_k Q_{i,k}Q_{k,j} &= \delta_{i,j} &&\text{for all $i,j$}
\end{align}

---

Not guaranteed globally optimal, but here are some locally optimal solutions for small $n$:

\begin{pmatrix}
1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0.70711 & 0.70711 \\
0.70710 & -0.70711 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-0.33333 & 0.66667  & -0.66667 \\
0.66667  & -0.33333 & -0.66667 \\
-0.66667 & -0.66667 & -0.33333 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-0.5 & 0.5 & -0.5 & 0.5 \\ 
0.5 & -0.5 & -0.5 & 0.5 \\ 
-0.5 & -0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\ 
0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0.54545 & 0.18182 & -0.54545 & 0.27273 & -0.54545 \\ 
0.18182 & -0.54545 & 0.27273 & -0.54545 & -0.54545 \\ 
-0.54545 & 0.27273 & -0.54545 & -0.54545 & -0.18182 \\ 
0.27273 & -0.54545 & -0.54545 & -0.18182 & 0.54545 \\ 
-0.54545 & -0.54546 & -0.18182 & 0.54545 & -0.27273 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0.44721 & -0.44721 & 0.00000 & 0.44721 & -0.44721 & -0.44721 \\ 
-0.44721 & 0.44721 & 0.44721 & 0.44721 & 0.00000 & -0.44721 \\ 
0.00000 & 0.44721 & -0.44721 & 0.44721 & -0.44721 & 0.44721 \\ 
0.44721 & 0.44721 & 0.44721 & -0.44721 & -0.44721 & 0.00000 \\ 
-0.44721 & 0.00000 & -0.44721 & -0.44721 & -0.44721 & -0.44721 \\ 
-0.44721 & -0.44721 & 0.44721 & 0.00000 & -0.44721 & 0.44721 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0.078604 & 0.443778 & -0.443778 & -0.443778 & 0.095525 & -0.443778 & 0.443778 \\ 
0.443778 & 0.095524 & 0.365175 & -0.365174 & -0.443778 & 0.443778 & 0.365174 \\ 
-0.443778 & 0.365175 & -0.443778 & 0.269651 & -0.443779 & 0.443778 & 0.078603 \\ 
-0.443779 & -0.365175 & 0.269651 & 0.078604 & -0.443778 & -0.443778 & 0.443778 \\ 
0.095523 & -0.443778 & -0.443778 & -0.443778 & -0.443778 & -0.078603 & -0.443778 \\ 
-0.443778 & 0.443778 & 0.443778 & -0.443778 & -0.078604 & -0.095524 & -0.443779 \\ 
0.443778 & 0.365175 & 0.078604 & 0.443778 & -0.443778 & -0.443778 & -0.269651 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0.35355 & -0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 & -0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 \\ 
-0.35355 & 0.35355 & -0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 & -0.35355 & 0.35355 & -0.35355 \\ 
0.35355 & -0.35355 & -0.35355 & 0.35355 & -0.35355 & -0.35355 & -0.35355 & -0.35355 \\ 
0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 & -0.35355 & -0.35355 \\ 
0.35355 & 0.35355 & -0.35355 & 0.35355 & -0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 \\ 
-0.35355 & -0.35355 & -0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 & -0.35355 & 0.35355 \\ 
0.35355 & 0.35355 & -0.35355 & -0.35355 & 0.35355 & -0.35355 & -0.35355 & 0.35355 \\ 
0.35355 & -0.35355 & -0.35355 & -0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 & 0.35355 & -0.35355 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-0.39434 & 0.18301 & -0.39434 & 0.18301 & 0.18301 & -0.39434 & -0.34429 & 0.39434 & -0.39434 \\ 
0.18301 & -0.39434 & 0.18301 & -0.39434 & -0.39434 & 0.18301 & -0.34429 & 0.39434 & -0.39434 \\ 
-0.39434 & 0.18301 & 0.18301 & -0.39434 & 0.39434 & 0.39434 & -0.34429 & 0.18301 & 0.39434 \\ 
0.18301 & -0.39434 & -0.39434 & 0.18301 & 0.39434 & 0.39434 & -0.34429 & -0.39434 & -0.18301 \\ 
0.18301 & -0.39434 & 0.39434 & 0.39434 & 0.18301 & -0.39434 & -0.34429 & 0.18301 & 0.39434 \\ 
-0.39434 & 0.18301 & 0.39434 & 0.39434 & -0.39434 & 0.18301 & -0.34429 & -0.39434 & -0.18301 \\ 
-0.35437 & -0.35437 & -0.35437 & -0.35437 & -0.35437 & -0.35437 & -0.15470 & -0.35437 & 0.35437 \\ 
0.39434 & 0.39434 & 0.18301 & -0.39434 & 0.18301 & -0.39434 & -0.34429 & -0.39434 & -0.18301 \\ 
-0.39434 & -0.39434 & 0.39434 & -0.18301 & 0.39434 & -0.18301 & 0.34429 & -0.18301 & -0.39434 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.00000 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 \\ 
-0.33333 & 0.00000 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 \\ 
0.00000 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 \\ 
0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.00000 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 \\ 
0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.00000 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 \\ 
-0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.00000 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 \\ 
0.33333 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.00000 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 \\ 
0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.00000 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 \\ 
-0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.00000 \\ 
0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & -0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.33333 & 0.00000 & -0.33333 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: That is exactly the setup I am referring to as the quadratic programming problem in my comment following/below the question. As I said, I did not have a quadratic programming package at hand. What does your numerical solution look like for some $n$'s? More importantly, do you have any idea as to what the general solution would be?

Comment: I doubt there is a general solution. If there is a Hadamard matrix of order $n$, then it gives you a solution with all entries having the same absolute value. It is conjectured that there are Hadamard matrices of order $n$ for all multiples of four, but not proved.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Very useful information. My question stated my first idea was to try exactly what you called the Hadamard matrix but found it to fail to exist for odd dimensions. But Hadamard conjecture is nice.