# Quadratic Forms in $k^n$ for a general field $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, quadratic-forms, multilinear-algebra

I've read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1142262/342631) that any quadratic form over $k^n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\text{char}(k)\neq 2$ is diagonalizable.

But considering $k=\mathbb{Q}$, which has characteristic $0$, the quadratic form $2x^2+2xy+y^2$ defined in $k^2$ is not diagonalizable, right?

What am I missing?

Comment: $2x^2+2xy+y^2=x^2+(x+y)^2$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I've just realized my confusion. I was thinking about the eigenvalue decomposition of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 \\
    1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$, which isn't possible in $\mathbb{Q}$ for this case.

Comment: Diagonalizing a quadratic form is easier than diagonalizing a matrix. The relevant matrix transformation is $M \mapsto QMQ^T$, not $M \mapsto QMQ^{-1}$, and in particular it does not preserve eigenvalues.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, what's the algorithm for $M\mapsto QMQ^{T}$?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to diagonalize quadratic forms? Basically the idea is to repeatedly complete the square, like Lord Shark did above.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I was wondering about the general case for $k^n$. For example, take $n=3$ and the quadratic form $z^2-xy$. Completing the square doesn't apply here, right?

Comment: There you can instead "produce a square": $xy = \frac{(x + y)^2 - (x - y)^2}{4}$.